# Как соединиться с хостом с помощью сокета зная его внешний и локальный ip в c#

Tags: c#, сокеты, протоколы

Я хочу общаться с сервером с помощью сокета, но не знаю как добраться до устройства. Я могу найти в локальной сети ip адрес который мне нужен, но что дальше? У меня на руках внешний ip адрес устройства и его локальный ip адрес и порт, на котором работает приложение. Что мне делать дальше? Можно обойтись без Upnp и DHCP?

Comment: Зависит от того в какой сети будет то приложение которое будет подключаться к вашему хосту с которым вы хотите соединиться, если вы с ним в одной сети то напрямую по локальному ip если вы во внешней а хост во внутренней то надо на роутере настроить проброс того порта по которому вы будете подключатся к хосту от роутера к хосту и соответсвенно в приложении уже указывать внешний ip роутера

Comment: Где почитать про это можно?

Comment: я в свое время читал Таненбаума Компьютерные сети, если ваша специализация так или иначе связана с ними то эта книга будет для вас не лишняя https://www.google.com/search?q=ISBN+5-318-00492-X

Comment: У меня нет специализации), но спасибо)